# Embedd Swagger UI into Blazor Server Side App

Tags: rest, swagger-ui, blazor-server-side, c#-5.0

I would like to embed the swagger UI in a page on my blazor app. I am having a hard time finding examples of how to do this with razor pages. Does anyone have any examples doing this? I am usually more of a back end developer so struggling a bit getting this front end up and running.

Answer (score 8):

Although this is quite an old issue, I've decided to try and find the answer as I wanted to embed the Swagger UI into one of my pages myself.
It turns out that it is quite easy to do it!
All credits go to [this repository](https://github.com/jsauve/WebApiPlusBlazorWithAuth0JwtAndCookies) - owner 'jsauve'.

He shows that you can do it:
[image]

Here are the steps that you need to do in order for it to show on your page:

0. Install `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` on your Blazor Server.
1. In Startup.cs, ConfigureServices add:

```
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });
```

2. In Startup.cs, Configure add:

```
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
            });
```

3. Simply, create Razor Component and add:

```
            @page "/test"

            <iframe src="swagger" style="width:90%;height:1200px;border:none;" />
```

Navigate to `/test` from your e.g. MainLayout.razor. I hope it can help somebody because it certainly helped me.

Comment: not working here ;-/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with JS Interop after rendering.

Setup Swagger as in Program.cs using their documentation.
In Startup.cs, Include Swagger, but not swagger UI.

Then create your `.razor` page like this

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@page "/docs/view"

@inject IJSRuntime JS
    
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5.10.0/swagger-ui.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5.10.0/swagger-ui-bundle.js" crossorigin></script>
<script>
        window.loadswagger = function () {
        const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
            url: '@($"{NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("swagger/v1/swagger.json")}")',
            dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
            presets: [
                SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis
            ]
        })
        window.ui = ui
    }
</script>

@code {
    private ElementReference divElement;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("loadswagger");
        }
    }
}
```

This page will contain the embedded swagger.
Be ready for some possible CSS conflicts between their stylesheet and your app's.

You can then apply your own CSS, and add more interaction between your app and the swagger UI.